# Spring Jpa repository find all returns empty list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have connected spring boot to an MySQL database running on a VPS. I've mapped the entity class, repository, service and controller. But when calling the get method for "findAll" I get an empty list in postman. When I query the table in MySQL workbench I do get data, so its not empty.

Did I miss something?

My entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Requests {

    @Id
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private Long url_id;

    @Column
    private Date timestamp;

    @Column
    private String method;

    @Column
    private String document;

    @Column
    private String mime_type;

    @Column
    private char is_html;

    @Column
    private int status_code;

    @Column
    private String reason;

    @Column
    private String cookies;

    @Column
    private String request;

    @Column
    private String response;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getUrl_id() {
        return url_id;
    }

    public void setUrl_id(Long url_id) {
        this.url_id = url_id;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }

    public void setMethod(String method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public String getDocument() {
        return document;
    }

    public void setDocument(String document) {
        this.document = document;
    }

    public String getMime_type() {
        return mime_type;
    }

    public void setMime_type(String mime_type) {
        this.mime_type = mime_type;
    }

    public char getIs_html() {
        return is_html;
    }

    public void setIs_html(char is_html) {
        this.is_html = is_html;
    }

    public int getStatus_code() {
        return status_code;
    }

    public void setStatus_code(int status_code) {
        this.status_code = status_code;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }

    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    public String getCookies() {
        return cookies;
    }

    public void setCookies(String cookies) {
        this.cookies = cookies;
    }

    public String getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setRequest(String request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

My reposiroty:

```
public interface RequestsRepository extends JpaRepository<Requests, Long> {
}
```

My service:

```
@Service
public class RequestsService {

    private final RequestsRepository requestsRepository;


    public RequestsService(RequestsRepository requestsRepository) {
        this.requestsRepository = requestsRepository;
    }

    public List<RequestsDTO> findAll() {
        return requestsRepository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(requests -> mapToDTO(requests, new RequestsDTO()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }



    private RequestsDTO mapToDTO(final Requests requests, final RequestsDTO requestsDTO) {
        requestsDTO.setId(requests.getId());
        requestsDTO.setUrl_id(requests.getUrl_id());
        requestsDTO.setTimestamp(requests.getTimestamp());
        requestsDTO.setMethod(requests.getMethod());
        requestsDTO.setDocument(requests.getDocument());
        requestsDTO.setMime_type(requests.getMime_type());
        requestsDTO.setIs_html(requests.getIs_html());
        requestsDTO.setStatus_code(requests.getStatus_code());
        requestsDTO.setReason(requests.getReason());
        requestsDTO.setCookies(requests.getCookies());
        requestsDTO.setRequest(requests.getRequest());
        requestsDTO.setResponse(requests.getResponse());
        return requestsDTO;
    }

    private Requests mapToEntity(final RequestsDTO requestsDTO, final Requests requests) {
        requests.setId(requestsDTO.getId());
        requests.setUrl_id(requestsDTO.getUrl_id());
        requests.setTimestamp(requestsDTO.getTimestamp());
        requests.setMethod(requestsDTO.getMethod());
        requests.setDocument(requestsDTO.getDocument());
        requests.setMime_type(requestsDTO.getMime_type());
        requests.setIs_html(requestsDTO.getIs_html());
        requests.setStatus_code(requestsDTO.getStatus_code());
        requests.setReason(requestsDTO.getReason());
        requests.setCookies(requestsDTO.getCookies());
        requests.setRequest(requestsDTO.getRequest());
        requests.setResponse(requestsDTO.getResponse());
        return requests;
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/crawler", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class RequestsController {

    private final RequestsService requestsService;


    public RequestsController(RequestsService requestsService) {
        this.requestsService = requestsService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<RequestsDTO>> getAllRequests() {return ResponseEntity.ok(requestsService.findAll()); }
}
```

**EDIT**

My crawler domain config

```
/**
 * Data source for the MySQL crawler database
 */
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = "cs.crawler.server.projectcs.domain.crawlerdb")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "cs.crawler.server.projectcs.repos.crawlerdb")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class CrawlerDomainConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.crawler")
    public DataSourceProperties crawlerDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.crawler.configuration")
    public HikariDataSource secondDataSource(DataSourceProperties secondDataSourceProperties) {
        return secondDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

}
```

My config YAML:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    users:
      url: ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL:jdbc:h2:mem:projectcs}
      username: ${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME:sa}
      password: ${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD:}
    crawler:
      url: ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL:jdbc:mysql://VPSIPHERE:3306/darcweb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=false}
      username: ${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME:root}
      password: ${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD:mypassword}
  dbcp2:
    max-wait-millis: 30000
    validation-query: "SELECT 1"
    validation-query-timeout: 30
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    open-in-view: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
        id:
          new_generator_mappings: true
springdoc:
  pathsToMatch: /api/**
```

Comment: 95% empty database

Comment: What is the API endpoint you are using in postman?

Comment: Try to add @Table annotation to Entity

Comment: Are you really sure the database on the VPS has data in it? How are you connecting to it with MySQL workbench to see there's data?

Comment: @Kayaman yes through workbench

Comment: @Umeshwaran A get on localhost:8080/api/crawler

Comment: @potiev I added @Table(name = "requests") still an empty list

Comment: what is the table in the database?

Comment: @shivanithakur requests

Comment: does you pom.xml have h2 database in it as dependency by any chance? And please show us your datasource configuration

Comment: @JAsgarov yes, I have two datasources one is MySql(which returns empty list) and an H2database

Comment: well there you go - you are using wrong database. Make sure you set it up correctly in application.properties or whatever you are using as datasource onfiguration

Comment: @JAsgarov is it not possible to use two different databases? I have both the MySQL and H2 configured in my YML config and I have two Config classes for each DB with the H2 marked as primary

Comment: you want to persist to both databases at the same time?? Usually people use outside database for runtime and h2 for tests or something

Comment: @JAsgarov might be right.Check which the java is pointing while starting. It might be pointing to H2 while you are executing SQL in SQL DB.

Comment: (in contrary to baeldung tutorial) the databases have different vendors!!(?) (`spring.datasource.driver-class-name` + dependencies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 datasoruce dependencies (mysql and h2). You need to specify which datasource for spring to use - it picks h2 by default which is the reason you don't find anything.

Add following lines to your application.properties file to specify the database:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASE_NAME
spring.datasource.username=USERNAME
spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD
```

To use h2 for tests for example you can overwrite application.properties for h2 under your test folder in resources

In case you want to use both databases simultaneously in your application you would need to define both and set them in runtime into your enviroment like shown here:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: I just edited my question. I have both configured in my YAML file, for the H2 I also have a domain config but marked with Primary

Comment: I feel like I have answered your question to what the problem is and ways to go around solving it. Since h2 is primary obviously it picks that and ignores the other

Comment: I have switched to use only MySQL for both datasources, thanks for the help!